# Sqlite database does not store previous data inserted

Tags: sqlite, python-2.7

Hi i'm new to python and sqlite and i was just testing a simple coding as below
import sqlite3

```
os.chdir("C:\Backup")
conn = sqlite3.connect('FBG.db')
c=conn.cursor()
c.execute('''create table if not exists A (time INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, data REAL)''')
data=(1,2)
c.execute("insert into A (time, data) values (?,?)", data)

c.execute('SELECT * FROM A ORDER BY time').fetchall()

c.close()
```

So the problem is every time, i run the code, i was assuming it will store the pervious data, the list of database will become bigger, but what happened is that no matter how many times i have run it, all the data in this table is still (1,2) which i though should be many (1,2). So i was wondering what's the reason for that? because to me it does't make any difference from "insert" or "insert or replace".

**EDIT:**

```
with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        entries = csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t')
        rows= list(entries)
    ###    
    # For first point (A) three strain values and temperature
    ###

    ###use numpy to turn the csv files into a matrix  
        matrix= numpy.array([])
        for i in range (1,5) :   #in the setted files using len(list(rows)) to make it read all the coloumn and create a new table for each different coloumn
            a=list(rows[3])
            result = [0,0]
    # the program will detect the number and name for each coloumn then show add new table untill there's no more coloumn left 
            for r in range(5,len(rows)):
                data=list(rows[r])
                c.execute("create table if not exists " + str(a[i]) + file[0:4] + file[4:6] + " (time real, data real)") # NEED TO CHANGE TABLE NAME FROM A TO B OR C OR ETC
                matrix=numpy.append(matrix,float(data[0]))
                matrix=numpy.append(matrix,float(data[i]))
                result= numpy.vstack((result,matrix))
                matrix=[]
    # create a sqlite table named by its point in this case is A with different name to the coloumn
                result = numpy.delete(result, (0), axis=0)
                for item in result:
                    c.execute("insert into " + str(a[i]) + file[0:4] + file[4:6] +  " values (?,?)", item)
```

Comment: You cannot have two records with the same primary key. (You should get an error message when trying to insert the duplicate.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @CL was saying you can't have 2 records with the same `PRIMARY KEY`

this Table should be built with 3 columns.

1. `A_ID` PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT NOT NULL
2. `time` DATETIME (probably `NOT NULL` as well
3. `data` REAL

---

in other words, Never set the Primary key in your code, let the database auto increment it for you, or use a GUID.

this line

```
data=(1,2)
```

is the only thing that is being inserted into your database.  so the only record in the database will be the one you insert, which is `1,2`

Comment: But i have run the program several times which i assumed it means add data=(1,2) to the same database, so it should be having mutiple data in it? And i have used similar code when i was adding data to the table, i have attached code in the question, in that case, the code just add any data in the database regardless whether its repetitive or not. I was trying to figure out the reason for that.

Comment: in the big block of code you are adding new rows dynamically, they are never the same. and you aren't trying to set the Primary key of the row either.  that code creates a new table every time and a new row, so it looks like there is a bunch of tables with one row each

Comment: Still trying to figure out why the "insert" in both code gives out different result. But thanks anyway :)